# Group results of function in php

Tags: php, mysql, grouping

Hi there I have a query result that gives me 2 elements starting the same but ending diferently, this way:

- btdeucat_de
- btdeucat_ca

By means of a php function I can eliminate the difference, but the echo still gives me 2 elements, how can I group them to form just one element:

- btdeucat

(I have tried GROUP BY at the query but that does not help because at the db names are different)

Here's the code I have:

```
<?php
$result0 = mysqli_query($dbiac, "SELECT * FROM corpus_info WHERE corpus IN (SELECT corpus FROM corpus_alignments)") or die(mysqli_error($dbiac));
while($cpsblg = mysqli_fetch_array($result0)){

// eliminate the difference and echo it to the page
$cpsblg = preg_replace('"_(de|en|ca|es|fr|it|pt)$"', '', $cpsblg['corpus']);
echo $cpsblg."<br />";
?>
```

Results in:

- btdeucat
- btdeucat

Comment: Store already echoed `$cpsblg` somewhere and compare.

Comment: Push is in an array with same key it will overwrite and get the results after loop ends.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more, please

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…”)` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean the db names are different?
Are the two elements you get are from two different DB? (Like one element from each db?)

Comment: @tadman Thanks for your comment, I'll try to put in practice what you say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just do this?

```
SELECT c.corpus_initial
FROM (SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(corpus, '_', 1) AS corpus_initial
      FROM corpus_info 
      WHERE corpus IN (SELECT corpus FROM corpus_alignments)) c
GROUP BY c.corpus_initial
```

Comment: Thanks, that works, there are those who have the knowledge and we the other ones that still have to learn a lot!